# Find the nearest Ancestor with certain property

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Is there a way in a `Style` to bind a property setter value to the nearest parent that has provided a value for that property? For example if I have the following hierarchy:

`Window` > `Grid` > `GroupBox` > `Grid` > `TextBox`

and I write the following `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Converter="{StaticResource TagToVisibilityConverter}"
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" Path="Tag" />
            </Binding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This will simply go to the top-level parent (`Window`) and fetch the Tag property. What I want it is to search for the nearest parent that has used `Tag` property, For instance, in the above hierarchy, if `UserControl` specifies a `Tag` and so does the `GroupBox`, it should fetch the value from `GroupBox`. I was thinking of some clever usage of `AncestorLevel`, but it looks it won't be that straight. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [Property Value Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197.aspx) is what you need. According the article,

> To make a property participate in value inheritance, create a custom attached property, as described in [How to: Register an Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753957.aspx). Register the property with metadata ([FrameworkPropertyMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.aspx)) and specify the "Inherits" option in the options settings within that metadata. Also make sure that the property has an established default value, because that value will now inherit.

If you want something more special, you can write your own [markup extention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) which will use the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) class to walk through the WPF Visual Tree and look up the element you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check for the first `FrameworkElement` since `FrameworkElement` is the class that contains the `Tag` property.

```
RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=FrameworkElement}" Path="Tag"
```

Comment: I'm not looking for the nearest parent that implements Tag property, but for the nearest parent that specifies a value for this property.